# Consuming given amount of messages from channel with period

Tags: spring, spring-integration

*Question firstly to Artem Bilan (I work with your former colleagues)*

I have such flow:

- **JdbcPollingChannelAdapter** for getting dataset ASAP (because of DB is bottleneck in flow)
- **CHAIN_OF_TRANSFORMATORS** (due to business requirements)
- **ServiceActivator** for sending JMS using `JmsTemplate`

According to requirements I have to send different amounts of messages per static period (it provided by some "profile" having "10,20,100..." structure, means "send 10 messages during first minute, 20 msg during second minute, 100 msg during third minute..."). 
Implementing of periods is enough trivial, it provided by `PeriodicPoller`.

The issue is the first part of requirement. Case of getting given amount of table rows by `JdbcPollingChannelAdapter` implemented using `SqlParameterSource`, but isn't fit as mentioned above "bottleneck" reason. Is it possible to "get N messages from channel"?

I tried to implement it with some `ReleaseStrategy` on channel next to adapter, but have no luck combining it with periodic polling. If somebody help me I will describe in details used approaches.

Additional difficulty related with describing integration flow context using Java DSL, meantime most part of examples use XML.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: Hi! Thank you for the attention to my person and give a "Hello!" to those my former colleagues. I'll take a look to your use-case soon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the private discussion with Dmitrii we come up with this solution.

**Requirements**

- Read the particular amount of messages and send them to JMS queue one by one
- The amount of messages is changed on each poll interval
- Send messages and compare their amount with required one for that particular poll task. If they aren't equal produce an error report, that there was not enough messages for the poll.

**Solution**

1. Collect messages in the `QueueChannel`
2. Change `maxMessagesPerPoll` for the endpoint on each poll
3. The `<poller>` (`PollerMetadata`) has `adviceChain` option.
4. With that we can provide some custom `Advice` (`MethodInterceptor`)
5. Inject our `PollingConsumer` to it for changing `maxMessagesPerPoll` before `invocation.proceed()`
6. Use some `AtomicInteger` bean to increment in the `ChannelInterceptor#preSend` and `reset` in that `Advice`
7. In addition you can check the previous poll state in that advice comparing the `maxMessagesPerPoll` with the counter.